# Don't open edit post link in new tab

Tags: front-end

I have a little problem. I created a front-end edition panel. For that, I intercepted `get_edit_post` with `add_filter`, like this:

```
add_filter('get_edit_post_link', 'get_edit_post_link_178416', 99, 3);

function get_edit_post_link_178416($link, $post_id, $context) {
    if(is_admin())
        return $link;
    if(!is_singular('post'))
        return "";
    $lang = pll_current_language();
    $id_add_page = pll_get_post(249, $lang );

    return add_query_arg( 'id', $post_id, get_permalink($id_add_page));
}
```

But when I clicked on the link, it opens in a new tab. How can I avoid it?

NB: 249 is the ID of the edit page in French. The function `pll_get_post` of Polylang plugin gives me the post's ID in the current language.

Thanks in advance,
for your help.

Comment: where is this link that opens a new tab ? in the adminbar ?

Comment: No, it's the link below the article title. It's a specificity of each theme?

Comment: yes this link is theme specific. which one do you use ?

Comment: I use Customizr. I didn't know it was theme specific!

Comment: I just try this free theme Customizr and I found this link. the first step is to create a child theme (https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) to not loose the customisation on theme update. then you can e.g. redefine the function `czr_fn_edit_button` in the child theme.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! I was looking for that for almost two days! Thank you!! :)

Comment: just be aware than this function is used on several places in the theme.

Comment: Ok, I just removed the "target _blank". But I should check when updates :)